# NullPointerException encountered when converting RTF to PDF with iText 4.2.1

Tags: java, pdf, itext, rtf

A requirement was forwarded to me to convert a dynamic RTF document to PDF, populating all attributes in the RTF prior to conversion.

Following the exact example from this [blog post](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/11/24/convert-rtf-to-pdf-with-open-source-library-itext/), I encountered a `NullPointerException` when running the application.

*Note*: I know that RTF document support on iText has been [abandoned](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions%40lists.sourceforge.net/msg47892.html) but it is already used by the client.

The exact stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.destinations.RtfDestinationFontTable.importSystemFonts(RtfDestinationFontTable.java:571)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.destinations.RtfDestinationFontTable.init(RtfDestinationFontTable.java:206)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.destinations.RtfDestinationFontTable.setParser(RtfDestinationFontTable.java:190)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.destinations.RtfDestinationMgr.addDestination(RtfDestinationMgr.java:184)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.ctrlwords.RtfCtrlWordHandler.<init>(RtfCtrlWordHandler.java:175)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.ctrlwords.RtfCtrlWordMap.<init>(RtfCtrlWordMap.java:607)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.ctrlwords.RtfCtrlWordMgr.<init>(RtfCtrlWordMgr.java:93)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.RtfParser.init(RtfParser.java:655)
    at com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.RtfParser.convertRtfDocument(RtfParser.java:551)
    at za.co.sindi.utils.Prints.printToPDFWithIText(Prints.java:114)
    at za.co.sindi.utils.Prints.main(Prints.java:150)
```

The source example:

```
    public static void printToPDFWithIText() {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        Document document = null;

        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/testPDF.rtf")));
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/testPDF_" + System.nanoTime() + ".pdf")));
            document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
            document.open();
            RtfParser parser = new RtfParser(null);
            parser.convertRtfDocument(input, document); //NullPointerException is here (line 114)
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

//          if (document != null && document.isOpen()) {
//              document.close();
//          }
        }
    }
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The guilty culprit is the following implementation on [`com.lowagie.text.rtf.parser.destinations.RtfDestinationFontTable`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.1/com/lowagie/text/rtf/parser/destinations/RtfDestinationFontTable.java) class:

```
private Properties getEnvironmentVariables() throws Throwable {
    Properties environmentVariables = new Properties();
    String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = null;
    if (operatingSystem.indexOf("windows 95") > -1
            || operatingSystem.indexOf("windows 98") > -1
            || operatingSystem.indexOf("me") > -1) {
        process = runtime.exec("command.com /c set");
    } else if ((operatingSystem.indexOf("nt") > -1)
            || (operatingSystem.indexOf("windows 2000") > -1)
            || (operatingSystem.indexOf("windows xp") > -1)
            || (operatingSystem.indexOf("windows 2003") > -1)
            || (operatingSystem.indexOf("windows vista") > -1)) {
        process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c set");
    } else {
        process = runtime.exec("env");
    }
    BufferedReader environmentStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine = "";
    int idx = -1;
    while ((inputLine = environmentStream.readLine()) != null) {
        idx = inputLine.indexOf('=');
                inputLine.substring(idx + 1));
    }
}
```

The developer, obviously, checked for Windows Operating Systems starting from Windows 95 to Windows Vista. He/She forgot to check Windows 7 and Windows 8 environment.

The `System.getProperty("os.name");` returns `Windows 7` on my development workstation and, thus the `Runtime` tries to invoke the `env` process, which does **not** exists on a Windows environment. And since this throws a `Throwable`, the following instance occurs:

```
private void importSystemFonts() {
    Properties pr = null;
    try {
        pr = getEnvironmentVariables();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
    String systemRoot = pr.getProperty("SystemRoot");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String fileSeperator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    int r = FontFactory.registerDirectory(systemRoot + fileSeperator + "fonts");
}
```

As you can see, the `pr` field is `null` initially. Now, the guilty method (already mentioned) has thrown an exception and `importSystemFonts` does nothing to cater for it, though it catches it. Hence `pr` remains `null`.
the line `String systemRoot = pr.getProperty("SystemRoot");` now throws the `NullPointerException`.

**How do we resolve it?**

Before running your program, you will have to cheat a bit: Fool the library that it's not Windows 7 or higher. In my case, I set it to `Windows Vista`.

This **must** be place prior to executing your code:

```
System.setProperty("os.name", "Windows Vista");
```

Now, run your code and you will see the exception disappear.

*Note:* Seeing that this class is abandoned, USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK. I posted this to help others, if you're still using this version of iText.

Comment: It's not really that the author of the code **forgot** to check for Windows 7 or Windows 8, it's just that these OSes didn't exist when the code was written. And as you mentionned, support for RTF has been dropped from iText since then.

Comment: Not necessarily. iText 4.2.1 was released on July 2013 ([Maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext)). The class was bundled with the release. Windows 7 and Windows 8 was pretty much in existence then. I guess it wasn't tested when it was finally released.

Comment: iText 4.2.x is an unofficial fork from the official 2.1.x branch. The last version in this branch, 2.1.7, is dated [July 2009](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/217).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi You might want to inform mvnrepository that they host artifacts patched by unknown third parties (in the case of 4.2.1) which may or may not contain malevolent changes to the original library.

Comment: I would like to inform you that iText Software has claimed ownership of com.lowagie on Maven Central, and that an iText 4.2.2 pom was uploaded, which has a redirection to iText 5.x.x. So set your version fixed to 2.1.7 in your pom.xml (or to 4.2.1, or whatever version you are currently using). It would be a maven best practice anyway to have fixed version in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1:**

If you build the rft.jar anyway you can also just add one more condition to the above mentioned if:

```
|| (operatingSystem.indexOf("windows 7") > -1))
```

(Since this decides only what to call `(process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c set");)`)

**Update: (Version2)**

And an even better implementation is:

```
//1. delete method 'getEnvironmentVariables(...)' completely
//2. import system fonts like this:
private void importSystemFonts() {
 String systemRoot = System.getenv("SystemRoot");
 String fileSeperator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
 FontFactory.registerDirectory(systemRoot + fileSeperator + "fonts");
}
```